# Looking for a way to get data from a google chart into php variable

Tags: php, html

I have cretae a column chart using Google chart which display a aggregate value. I've add a listener to enable some action when a column is selected.
The listener works as the alert statement displays the element I'd like to use.
How can I save into a php variable the selected item.
I looking for the code to be added in the pp section at the bottom of the display code below .

```
    <div id="chart_div" style="height:400px;width:450px"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ["SousCat_Nom", "Valeur", { role: "style" } ],
                <?php  
                     while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultAll))  
                      {  
                           echo "['".$row4["SousCat_Nom"]."', ".$row4['Valeur']." ,'#4d5ae3'],";  
                      }  
                ?>
    
            ]);
            var options = {
            chart: {
                title: 'Dépenses par catégories ',
                }
            };
            var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
            chart.draw(data, options);
            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
            function selectHandler() {
                var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0,0];
                if (selectedItem) {
                    var value = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
                    alert('The user selected ' + value);
                    <?php 
            
                        // $data = ?????? ; 
                         
                
                    ?>
                    }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: You cannot execute PHP code in JavaScript like this. All you can is get these data in JS and call external PHP script with arguments, maybe with AJAX. Of course if Google's API allows that.

Comment: Hum, thanks . Never use AJAX.. will look to easy way to build something after learning. Any hints anyone?